# How to prove that f(x)=1/|x-t| is continuous but not bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose S is not closed: there is a point t in R, t not in S,  such that a sequence in S converges to t. Show that the function f: S-> R, defined by f(x) = 1/|x -t|, is continuous but not bounded.

Comment: Which part is your problem, continuity or boundedness?

Answer (score 0):

Composite of continuous function is continuous. then by $f(x)=|x|, g(x)=\frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0$ are continuous, and $|x-t|\neq 0, \forall x\in S$,we get the result.

For unboundedness, we need to show $\forall M\in \mathbb{N}, \exists x\in S$, s.t. $\frac{1}{|x-t|}>M$.

by assumption, $\exists \{x_n\} \in S$, s.t. $|x_n-t|\to 0$, then $\forall M>0$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|x_n-t|<\frac{1}{M}$, hence $\frac{1}{|x_n-t|}>M$ , you get the result.

Comment: Can you elaborate more by filling in details?

Comment: @camox do you understand the part of continuity?

Comment: It's boundedness part I'm not getting

Comment: @camox I have added more details.